# Puedo cosultar en mysql por id si tengo un array de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer una consulta dado un array de números id[1, 4, 6], esos números serían los id de trabajadores que  se ingresan por un multiselect, por lo que pueden variar, cómo podría hacer una consulta si por ejemplo requiero los datos [Nombre][Apellidos][Sueldo], estaba pensando en usar php, pero aún no se me ocurre algo claro.

Este es uno que hice cuando se selecciona un sólo id, como el multiselect me da un array anque sea un sólo dato, lo comparo así...

```
    $idPro=$_POST['idPro'];
    $idEmb = $_POST['idEmb'];
    $idEmb2 = $_POST['idEmb2'];
   

  if (count($idPro)==1){
        $query=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT fruta.id_embarque as embarque, fruta.id_productores as id, SUM(fruta.peso_kg) as kg from fruta
        where fruta.id_embarque =$idEmb AND FRUTA.id_productores=$idPro[0]
        GROUP by fruta.id_productores");
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: Podrías por favor editar y mostrar lo que llevas? Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y pudiera terminar cerrada, checa aquí [ask]

Comment: Sí puedes con PHP, pero depende de cómo vas a recibir los datos para armar la consulta: `SELECT Nombre, Apellidos, Sueldo FROM tabla WHERE id IN (1, 4, 6)`

Comment: Los datos los recibo de un multiselect en forma de array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás analizando si solo se recibió una ID, ahí deja la consulta con `id_productores = ID_RECIBIDA`, si es más de una, usa [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) para generar una cadena de IDs separadas por coma `[ID1, ID2, IDX]` y el operador **IN** en vez de **=**

```
$idPro = $_POST['idPro'];
$idEmb = $_POST['idEmb'];
$idEmb2 = $_POST['idEmb2'];


if(count($idPro)==0) {
  // La consulta fallará si no se proporciona ID
  die('Selecciona al menos 1 ID');
} elseif(count($idPro)==1) {
  // Operador = y solo una ID
  $ids = "= {$idPro[0]}";
} else {
  // Operador IN y lista de IDs separadas por coma
  $ids = 'IN (' . implode(', ', $idPro) . ')';
}
$query=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT fruta.id_embarque as embarque, fruta.id_productores as id, SUM(fruta.peso_kg) as kg from fruta
    where fruta.id_embarque =$idEmb AND FRUTA.id_productores $ids
    GROUP by fruta.id_productores");
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```